# Using MySQL to calculate balances from debits and credits in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following MySQL table containing debit or credit "actions" with associated amounts, how is it possible to select all CLIENT_IDs with a non-zero "balance"? I have tried joining the table to itself in order to calculate all debit and credit totals, but something isn't working correctly.

```
CLIENT_ID    ACTION_TYPE    ACTION_AMOUNT
1            debit          1000
1            credit         100
1            credit         500
2            debit          1000
2            credit         1200
3            debit          1000
3            credit         1000
4            debit          1000
```

My MySQL query that doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
    client_id,
    SUM(t_debits) AS debits, 
    SUM(t_credits) AS credits, 
    SUM(t_debits)-SUM(t_credits) AS balance
FROM table_name AS t_debits
LEFT JOIN table_name AS t_credits ON t_credits.client_id=t_debits.client_id
WHERE 
    t_debits.action_type='debit'
    AND t_credits.action_type='credit'
    AND balance!=0
GROUP BY t_debits.client_id, t_credits.client_id;
```

The result I am expecting is something like:

```
CLIENT_ID    DEBITS    CREDITS    BALANCE
1            1000      600        400
2            1000      1200       -200
4            1000      0          1000
```

I have no idea what else to try. Any help would be great.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: AND balance!=0 doesn't work. You have to use `having` SUM(t_debits)-SUM(t_credits)<>0

Comment: GROUP BY t_debits.client_id, t_credits.client_id; is not nesseary if t_debits.client_id = t_credits.client_id. You only need GROUP BY t_debits.client_id

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(transaction_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,client_id INT NOT NULL
,action_type VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,action_amount INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table(client_id,action_type,action_amount) VALUES
(1            ,'debit',         1000),
(1            ,'credit',         100),
(1            ,'credit',         500),
(2            ,'debit',          1000),
(2            ,'credit',         1200),
(3            ,'debit',          1000),
(3            ,'credit',         1000),
(4            ,'debit',          1000);


SELECT client_id
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'debit' THEN action_amount END,0)) total_debits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'credit' THEN action_amount END,0)) total_credits
     , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'debit' THEN action_amount END,0)) 
     - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'credit' THEN action_amount END,0)) balance 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP  
    BY client_id
HAVING balance <> 0;


+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
| client_id | total_debits | total_credits | balance |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
|         1 |         1000 |           600 |     400 |
|         2 |         1000 |          1200 |    -200 |
|         4 |         1000 |             0 |    1000 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: +1 . . . I prefer this method because it uses a `having` clause instead of a subquery.

Comment: Me too - although I like the "ELSE 0" part of the other method.

Comment: . . This is your answer.  You can add in the `else 0` and remove the `coalesce()`.

Comment: After taking a closer look I have decided to go for this one as the answer, with the modification that @GordonLinoff suggested. I prefer doing this without using a subquery.

Comment: @user2959229 . . . In other databases, it wouldn't make a difference but MySQL materializes subqueries (yuck!).  Even in this case, it makes little difference, because the `group by` has to read and write the data multiple times.  However, when using MySQL, I just think it is better form to avoid subqueries except when necessary.

Comment: @Strawberry, I had created the same table structure, now the balance is calculating correctly. I have an issue of how I can get only debtors and only creditors because I am creating a report for both? If you can answer it than I can ask a question. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `case` statement

```
select client_id, debits, credits, debits-credits as balance
from (SELECT 
client_id,
SUM(case when ACTION_TYPE='debit' then action_amount else 0 end) AS debits, 
SUM(case when ACTION_TYPE='credit' then action_amount else 0 end) AS credits
FROM categories 
GROUP BY client_id) a
where debits-credits<>0;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c74711/9)

Comment: This appears to work correctly. Going to test to make double sure! Thanks.

Comment: Lemme know if there is any issue

Comment: This one did the job, but I've gone with the other answer that does not use a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS SMALLEST QUERY

```
        select CLIENT_ID,
                    sum(if(ACTION_TYPE='credit',ACTION_AMOUNT,0)) as credit,
                    sum(if(ACTION_TYPE='debit',ACTION_AMOUNT,0)) as debit,
                    sum(if(ACTION_TYPE='credit',ACTION_AMOUNT,-1*ACTION_AMOUNT)) as balance
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
        GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: If you could explain how your query works, it would make this a real answer.

Comment: This is not working SQL error:

ERROR:  function if(boolean, double precision, double precision) does not exist