# SQL calculate balances from debits and credits in a single table

Tags: mysql

The following table is containing debit or credit "actions". I want to find the ballance from a customer :

```
CLIENT_ID | ACTION_TYPE | ACTION_AMOUNT
10        | credit      | 100$ 
10        | debit       |  62$
10        | credit      |  62$
```

based on this code : [Using MySQL to calculate balances from debits and credits in a single table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826750/using-mysql-to-calculate-balances-from-debits-and-credits-in-a-single-table)

```
SELECT client_id
 , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'debit' THEN action_amount END,0)) total_debits
 , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'credit' THEN action_amount END,0)) total_credits
 , SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'debit' THEN action_amount END,0)) 
 - SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN action_type = 'credit' THEN action_amount END,0)) balance
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE CLIENT_ID = 10
 GROUP  
    BY client_id
HAVING balance <> 0;
```

The fowling code gives as result : Ballance -100, it's correct but in Finance it's Wrong;

Let's analyze the actions :

```
1 -> customer gives payment in advance 100$ (credit)
2 -> customer invoice 62$ (debit)
3 -> customer pays invoice 62$ (credit) 
4 -> ballance is -38$ not -100$
```

What should i do to get the correct Ballance, redesign the "Action" table or the SQL code? Set - to credit is not helping.

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: but -38 (-100+62) -  62  = -100 ..

Comment: That's a horrible table design, or at least insufficient action types. So 'debit' means invoice and 'credit' means either payment or the same invoice again. Change this design. Don't try to fight it with weird queries.

Comment: @scaisEdge , yes -100 on the SQL code is correct but when you analyze the cutomer tansactions it should -38$

Comment: @ThorstenKettner , thank you, i know it's a horibble table design i am testing it, searching over the internet i din't find any solution. Do you have any idea to redisign the transaction table ? There are 3 actions 1. Invoice (debit) 2. Payment (credit) 3. Payment in advance (credit).

Comment: Well, there are several options. So far there are two different actions that are both named 'credit', a real payment (the 100$) and a withdrawal from that amount (the 62$). These should at least have different acion names. Or just don't write a letter for the withdrawal; if the money (100$) covers the invoices (62$) they are paid, otherwise not.

Comment: Better may be another design, e.g. a table for real payments (100$) and a table for invoices (62$) with a status for paid and unpaid. Database tables represent entities, but a payment is something else than an invoice, so these should usually be different tables. Think about what you need. It seems strange there is no invoice table with an invoice number and an invoice date and yet another table with invoice positions.

Comment: Ehhh, no. This is correct. In your table and customer DID pay $162 and got a $62 bill. The 3rd action is NOT a real payment, not a credit. You have applied a wrong term (credit) to this transaction.

1. credit $100

2. debit $62

3. refund (debit) $38 => or 3 (apply) no financial transaction

Comment: @ThorstenKettner hello thank you for suggestions, yes they are 2 seperated tables for invoice and payment, this table is a transaction table that records invoices & payment of customers (with Payment ID & Invoice ID, dates etc). So what i understand is, to keep track the ballance for the customer, i must keep the last ballance (calculate) via code and not with a simple sql script with SUM as above.

Comment: Well, your main problem is that you give two things the same name. You look at a record and it says 'credit' and you don't know whether this is a transaction where you you got money from the customer or not. You should have two different names for the two different things. But when you think a bit more about all this, you suddenly notice that an invoice is not a transaction. So why is it in the transaction table?

Comment: So think about what you want to madel in your database. It seems there are payments and invoices and the payments don't refer to invoices. So well, have an invoice table and a payments table, get the sums of both and see the balance, I'd say.

Comment: Hello again, yes you are correct! But what happens when the customer says "Ok take this 100$ and i will spend it from time from you (As payment in advance), this is debit. An invoice is credit because the customer must give me that money. Summing invoices & payment is easy but the problem in my example is what happens when the customer gives me a payment in advance. Yes the "payment in advance" is not connect with any invoice, my table design has connection between invoices and payments. The problem is the "payment in advance", it's only money. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, my solution is Calculate  Running Totals thanks again